# Load .so from directory relative to loading executable

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

For various reasons mostly to do with inertia, we don't have a `make install` target.

Rather, we build our large C++ codebase directly into an FHS-like tree;

```
output/
  bin/
  lib/
  etc/
  ...
```

We've recently switched some third-party libraries to dynamic linking, and so we push a number of `.so` libraries into `lib/`.

Now, we're used to being able to just launch our executables from `bin/`, but that no longer works because the loader doesn't search our `lib/` directory.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` would solve this, but we would prefer not to have to provide it before every single executable invocation, and we don't want to stick it in the shell's environment, because we typically switch between a number of different build trees in the same shell.

We've considered adding an `rpath` entry in the generated ELF, but relative paths are typically resolved against `$PWD`, not the executable's dirname.

Is there a way to nudge the loader to look in `dirname(argv[0])/../lib` for .so libs?

Basically, I understand that there are lots of ways we can change our habits to make this work (and probably should), but we prefer not to at this point, so can we coerce the Linux so loader to do what we want? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using `rpath` and `${ORIGIN}` macro, which is recognized by `ld.so` at runtime.

From `man ld.so`:

```
ld.so understands certain strings in an rpath specification 
(DT_RPATH or DT_RUNPATH); those strings are substituted as follows

$ORIGIN (or equivalently ${ORIGIN})
    This expands to the directory containing the application executable.
```

More variables are available. You don't need to coerce the loader to anything. It has the feature for you. :)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I don't suppose there's a way to achieve this even without `rpath`?

Comment: Windows has a concept of manifest files that you put next to the executable, to control stuff like this. It would be cool if there was a similar out-of-band mechanism for `ld,so`.

Comment: Most popular solution is to provide wrapper shell script that sets the environment and calls the binary. A lot of big projects do this. `IntelliJ IDEA` or `Android Studio` are two notable examples.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. We were hoping not to have to reeducate a bunch of developers who have all the executable names in their muscle memory. Anyway, great answer, thanks!

Comment: In that case I'd move `bin/app` to `bin/app.bin` and place wrapper script into `bin/app`. Nobody will see the difference. Firefox and Thunderbird used this approach. Don't forget to pass all arguments unchanged. :)